# Bootstrap select won't dropdown when datatables is included

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, datatables, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to use [Bootstrap select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), this works but only on the pages where `datatables` is not loaded. The problem is when I click on the bootstrap select it wont turn aria expended to true, the strange thing is: when I clicked on the select button and hit a key on my keyboard, it triggers the button and expands it.

I don't know if there is a quick fix for this or `datatables` and Bootstrap select won't work together.

My code:

```html
  <!--  // Header cdns
     DataTables -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css') }}">

 <!-- Bootstrap-Select -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
   
<!--  // select button -->
  <select data-live-search="true" name="stores" id="stores" class="form-control selectpicker">
       <option value="1" data-content="Amsterdam"></option>
   </select>

<!-- // footer cdns
  Bootstrap-Select -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- DataTables -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Dutch"></script>
```

Take note that this is not my full code but just the important parts of it.

Comment: Are any errors being reported in the inspector/console?

Comment: Nope nothing at all

Comment: Do you have Bootstrap Select control inside the table?

Comment: I was building an example for something else so decided to try the Bootstrap select.  Aria-expanded seems to work correctly for both inputs outside the table in within the table data.  Check it out: http://live.datatables.net/yaviyoce/1/edit

Comment: well, for some reason it wont work for me. Maybe because i don't append it with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was simple, i loaded it before the bootstrap.js file.. And it needs to be loaded after the bootstrap.js file.

Comment: I am confused. Did u load it before the bootstrap.js or after ?